# time.strftime() not getting the right time

Tags: python, datetime, time

I'm trying to make "Pray times remember" app in python, so to get the time i use `time.strftime`.
my code:

```py
from time import strftime

time_now = strftime("%I:%M %p")
fajr_time = "12:50 PM" # Same time
print(time_now is fajr_time)
```

Output:

```
False
```

When you print him it returns the same. When you use `len()` returns the same.
I used `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M %p")` but same thing.

Comment: Please have a look at [mre] - how's you problem supposed to be reproduced if it depends on *your* machine's time? What if that time simply is not 12:50 pm?

Comment: ...besides the problem that `is` is for a comparison of object identity, while it seems what you want here is comparison for equality; `==`

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
print(time_now is fajr_time)
```

It should be:

```
print("time_now is", fajr_time)
```

The original is doing a comparison check to see if `time_now` `is` the same object as `fajr_time`, which it never is.

Comment: No, you didn't understand me, I say why it returns `False`? because both of them is the same value.

Answer (score 1):

You should `==` for string comparison, not `is`, replace

```
print(time_now is fajr_time)
```

using

```
print(time_now == fajr_time)
```

Comment: Same thing, returns False.

Answer (score 0):

you get False because IS in `(time_now is fajr_time)` compares the location of time_now with memory location of fajr_time
it's same as you would be comparing their ids (id(time_now) == id(fajr_time))
you need to use ==
(time_now == fajr_time)

Comment: Same output, False

Comment: you did smth wrong. try again this option (time_now == fajr_time) if those str are same it will return True. Alternatively maybe you are trying to compare current time with the one you hardcoded in line fajr_time = "12:50 PM" # Same time